# Use one Form multiple times and CSRF Token

Tags: zend-framework, hash, zend-form, zend-form-element

i am using the Zend Hash Element in my Forms for avoiding CSRF.
Now i have the following issue:

The same form is rendered multiple times on a page.
As seen every form has the same CSRF Token.
While researching i found, that only the token of the first rendered form is used.

How can i implement the correct validation of every Hash element for every form?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a salt element should do the trick:

```
$this->addElement('hash', 'course_csrf', array(
                                            'ignore' => true,
                                            'salt' => 'unique'
                                             )
                 );
```